# Error with custom layer when using tf.function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I created a classification model using LSTM and Attention (custom layer). The model trains fine with `model.fit` or without using `tf.function`. But it gives this error when I use `tf.function` with gradient tape

`ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function.`

Attention Layer

```
class Attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
 
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name='attention_weight', shape=(input_shape[-1],1), 
                               initializer='random_normal', trainable=True)
        self.b=self.add_weight(name='attention_bias', shape=(input_shape[1],1), 
                               initializer='zeros', trainable=True)        
        super().build(input_shape)
 
    def call(self,x):
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        e = K.squeeze(e, axis=-1)   
        alpha = K.softmax(e)
        alpha = K.expand_dims(alpha, axis=-1)
        context = x * alpha
        context = K.sum(context, axis=1)
        return context
```

My model -

```
class TweetClassificationModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self,rnn_units,vocab_size,embedding_weights,emb_dim,input_len,
                 dropout=0.1,dense_units=100,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.emb = Embedding(vocab_size,emb_dim,weights=[embedding_weights])
        self.lstm = LSTM(rnn_units,return_sequences=True)
        self.dense = Dense(100,activation='relu')
        self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)
        self.out_put = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
        self.input_len = input_len 
    
    def call(self,x):
        x = self.emb(x)
        x = self.lstm(x)
        x = Attention()(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        return self.out_put(x)
    
    def summary(self):
        x = Input(shape=(self.input_len,))
        m = Model(x,self.call(x))
        return m.summary()
```

It referred me to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables). Wasn't of much help though

Comment: Maybe you should think about why you are creating some layers in the constructor, and others in `call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xdurch0 is right. You shouldn't be creating the layers inside the constructer function and then again in `call()` function. As per the error, `tf.Variable` is being created more than once, this is because you are initiating both the `Attention` and `BatchNormalization` layers as it is inside the call function. What you should be doing, is this -

```
def build(self,input_shape):
    self.attn = Attention()
    self.bn = BatchNormalization()
    '''and all the rest of the layers too, the same way they have been defined in the constructer function'''
    super().build(input_shape)
```

You can create layers inside the `__init__()` function, but its recommended to use the `build()` function instead, for this